# Renaming pdf files in sequential order using powershell

Tags: powershell, rename, sequential

I have a large number of pdf's that need renamed in sequential order. These were originally scanned into a single document, then extracted as separate files. When extracted, the name becomes "444026-444050 1", "444026-444050 2", etc. I am trying to rename all the files to match the document number ("444026-444050 1" would become "444026").

I found the following line of code that I can use in Powershell, but it seems that anything over 9 files there is a problem! Once I try it with 10 files, only the first file is saved correctly. The rest become jumbled (file 444027 has the contents of file 444035, then file 444028 has 444027, and 444029 has 444028, etc.)

I imagine there is some sort of problem with a loop, but am having difficulty fixing it.

Can someone help?
thanks

```
Dir *.pdf | ForEach-Object  -begin { $count=26 }  -process { rename-item $_ -NewName "4440$count.pdf"; $count++ }
```

Comment: if `444026-444050 1` would become `444026`, then what would `444026-444050 2` become? How are these potential duplicates to be resolved? Please clarify by directly updating your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in which Dir (which is an alias for Get-ChildItem) retrieves the items does not appear to be strictly guaranteed. Furthermore, if it is sorting it's probably sorting them as strings and "444026-444050 10" comes before "444026-444050 2" as strings. It might be worth inserting SortObject into your pipeline and using Split to get at the sequence number you care about:

```
Dir *.pdf | Sort-Object -Property {[int]$_.Name.Split()[1].Split(".")[0]} | ForEach-Object  -begin { $count=26 } -process { rename-item $_ -NewName "4440$count.pdf"; $count++ }
```

The key part is this new pipeline stage inserted after `Dir` and before `ForEach-Object`:

```
Sort-Object -Property {[int]$_.Name.Split()[1].Split(".")[0]}
```

This says to sort the output of `Dir` according to the whatever comes between the first space and the subsequent period, comparing those things as integers (not strings). This ensures that your results will be ordered and that you'll get them in numeric order, not lexicographic order.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` itself [always sorts](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/35c7b7842e7e206f8a6ccc2ab7077a49ad9e7fa6/src/System.Management.Automation/namespaces/FileSystemProvider.cs#L1781-L1782). You can simplify the number extraction to `[int] ($_.BaseName -replace '.+ ')`

Comment: Good point about the lexical sorting not equaling numerical, but the OP's loop as written simply increments and embeds a single number for each input file, which would turn "444026-444050 1" as the first file into "444026", and then  "444026-444050 2" into "444027", which means that the commonality of the "444026" prefix is lost. I think the OP's exact requirements need clarifying first.

Comment: The reason this works is because sort-object blocks until it has all the filenames.

Comment: @mklement0 Disagree.  `dir | rename-item -newname { 'pre' + $_.name }`  This creates an infinite loop for me.  Using parentheses or sort works around it.

Comment: You are correct, @js2010, with respect to _Windows PowerShell_ - I didn't realize that the pre-sorting behavior is exclusive to _PowerShell [Core] 6+_.

Answer (score 2):

Alright.  Let's see if this makes everybody happy.  Maybe you should try this with a backup copy of the files.

```
# make some test files in a new folder
# 1..20 | foreach {
#   if (! (test-path "44026-44050 $_.pdf")) { 
#     echo "44026-44050 $_" > "44026-44050 $_.pdf" }
# }

# rename and pad the first 9 old filenames with a 0 before the last digit for sorting
# is it less than 100 files?
1..9 | foreach {
  ren "44026-44050 $_.pdf" "44026-44050 0$_.pdf" -whatif
}

# make dir complete first with parentheses for powershell 5
# pad $count to 2 digits
# take off the -whatif if it looks ok
(dir *.pdf) | foreach { $count = 1 } {
    $padded = $count | foreach tostring 00
    rename-item $_ -newname 4440$padded.pdf -whatif; $count++ }
```

Comment: +1 very interesting. Do you think if I tried this but just printed out the names I could verify that the parentheses make a difference? Or I guess it's sort of like a race condition in that sometimes it might just get the list in one go and sometimes it might trickle items across more slowly?

Comment: You can’t tell without taking off the whatif.  Maybe try it on a copy.

Comment: To summarize: In _Windows PowerShell_ (v5.1-) you indeed _need_ `(...)` for the renaming to work correctly. While no longer strictly necessary in _PowerShell [Core] 6+_, because it [always sorts internally](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/35c7b7842e7e206f8a6ccc2ab7077a49ad9e7fa6/src/System.Management.Automation/namespaces/FileSystemProvider.cs#L1781-L1782), it's not a bad idea to still use `(...)` for conceptual clarity, especially given that this behavior could be considered an implementation detail.

Comment: (continued) _If_ enumerating over `Get-ChildItem`'s output as-is were enough, your solution would be effective; however, what was necessary in this case was to use _custom_ sorting of the file names, based on interpreting parts of the file names as _numbers_, as shown in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60174430/45375), where the use of `Sort-Object` _implicitly_ ensures that the renamed files don't interfere with the enumeration (because sorting invariably requires _collecting all input up front_).